# getNodeValue of XML when there are two similar tags in xml

Tags: java, dom, xml-parsing

I'm using DOM to parse xml, but have run into an issue. In my xml i have three tags namely **str**, **int** and **str**. Now while parsing i get the same value for both the **str** tags whereas they should be different.

**My XML**

```
<result name="response" numFound="62996" start="0">
    <doc>
        <str name="body">
            a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x  y z
        </str>
        <int name="content_id">123351</int>
        <str name="title">
            Alphabets
        </str>
    </doc>
</result>
```

**Code for xml parsing**

```
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputSource is = new InputSource();
        is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(gXml));
        Document doc = db.parse(is);
        NodeList infraline1 = doc.getElementsByTagName(node);

        sb.append("<results count=");
        sb.append("\"10\"");
        sb.append(">\r\n");

        for (int i = 0; i < infraline1.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node1 = infraline1.item(i);
            if (node1.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element element = (Element) node1;
                NodeList nodelist = element.getElementsByTagName("str");
                Element element1 = (Element) nodelist.item(0);
                NodeList body = element1.getChildNodes();
                sb.append("<result>\r\n");
                sb.append("<body>");
                    sb.append((body.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());
                sb.append("</body>\r\n");
                if (node1.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element element2 = (Element) node1;
                    NodeList nodelist1 = element2.getElementsByTagName("int");
                    Element element3 = (Element) nodelist1.item(0);
                    NodeList id = element3.getChildNodes();
                    sb.append("<id>");
                        sb.append(id.item(0).getNodeValue().trim());
                    sb.append("</id>\r\n");
                }
                if(node1.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                    Element element4 = (Element) node1;
                    NodeList nodelist2 = element4.getElementsByTagName("str");
                    Element element5 = (Element) nodelist2.item(0);
                    NodeList title = element5.getChildNodes();
                    sb.append("<title>");
                        sb.append(title.item(0)).getNodeValue());
                    sb.append("</title>\r\n");
                }
                sb.append("</result>\r\n"); 
            }
        }
        sb.append("</results>");
    }
```

Please help as i need to  get different values for both **str** node

Comment: I'm afraid that snippet of code is downright horrible. Can you not reduce it to something that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: The `if` statement `(node1.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)` Inside your `for` loop is defined three times and you make an assignment to `node1` only once. This does not make sense to me. First, you should simplify your code, then look at the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I only see the statements

```
Element element1 = (Element) nodelist.item(0);
```

and

```
Element element3 = (Element) nodelist.item(0);
```

Are you sure, you are accesing the right elements.

... and by the way. The code is really confused, because you are parsing and writing data at once. Try to put the parsed XML into an own `Object` or `Map` and than write (format) it